# DjangoRestFramework & Javascript: Fetch additional data

Tags: javascript, serialization, django-rest-framework, model, fetch

I would like to ask, if it's possible to create a response with related data from a second model? For example:

**models.py**

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ManufacturerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Manufacturer
        exclude = [
            'date_created',
        ]

class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = [
            'date_created',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_list_manufacturer(request):
    qs = Manufacturer.objects.all()
    serializer = ManufacturerSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_list_card(request):
    qs = Car.objects.all()
    serializer = CarSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Right know I'm using the fetch-method to receive the data for the *Car*...

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json)
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

...and the data looks like this:

```
0: {id: 1, name: 'Focus', manufacturer: 1},
1: {id: 2, name: 'F-150', manufacturer: 1},
2: {id: 3, name: 'Model S', manufacturer: 2}
```

**My question:**

Is it possible to get - for example - the *name* of the *manufacturer* into my response? Something like this?

```
0: {id: 1, name: 'Focus', manufacturer: 1, manufacturer__name: 'Ford'},
1: {id: 2, name: 'F-150', manufacturer: 1, manufacturer__name: 'Ford'},
2: {id: 3, name: 'Model S', manufacturer: 2, manufacturer__name: 'Tesla'}
```

Thanks for all your help and have a great sunday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object

Inside serializers.py add:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField

class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer__name = SerializerMethodField(help_text="Name of the Car Manufacturer")

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'manufacturer',
            'manufacturer__name',
        ]

    def get_manufacturer__name(self, instance: Car):
        return instance.manufacturer.name
```

Comment: Ok...so a little update: my own solution only works when loading the data! When trying to create data with the same serializer it fails (I have to create another one without the additional field). Your solution works perfectly fine with both situations! So, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

so I found the solution! Inside my **serializers.py** I changed the one for the *car* into this:

```
class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer_name = CharField(source='manufacturer.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = [
            'date_created',
        ]
```

Comment: Is it working as you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, it's working as expected! But thanks anyway for your solution!